# Writing Unit Tests for method that queries database

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I am learning TDD and I currently have a method that is working but I thought I'd have a go at rebuilding it using TDD.

The method essentially takes 6 parameters, queries a database, does some logic and returns a `List<T>`

My initial tests including checking for empty/zero defined string and int method parameter values but now I'm not sure what to do. If I wasn't using TDD, I would just create code to find the DB connection string and open up a DB connection, query the database, read the values etc.

Obviously we can't do that in Unit Testing so I was after some advice of how to proceed.

Comment: Nitpick - If it queries the database, it is an integration test, not a unit test.

Comment: @Oded:that's a matter of opinion and controversy.

Comment: @Oded - Ive said that sentence so many times at work it's unreal!

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I guess it depends on how one defines a unit and what the constrains on a unit test should be (speed, in process etc).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that TDD is as much about good design than it is about testing. This method has too much going on; it violates the Separation of Concerns principle.

You've already identified several areas that will need to be tested:

> The method essentially takes 6 parameters, queries a database, does some logic and returns a `List<T>`

You have several discrete steps there, and there are probably a few more hiding in the code. Breaking those up is the name of the game when it comes to TDD.

For starters, it might be a good idea to factor out the piece that performs the logic.

Is your method building a query dynamically? Break that piece out as well and test it to make sure the query is written properly.

You can put the execution of the query into a standalone repository or something similar, and write integration tests against that. That way you only have a simple test hitting the database instead of the current complex method.

If you try to test this as is, you'll likely end up with a monster test that requires a lot of setup and duplicates all of your business logic, and when it breaks it'll be unclear as to what went wrong.

Comment: So would say I should have a mock repository that just returns an in-memory list of data simulating that of the database calls?

Comment: Exactly. And your logic can act on that. This frees you up from relying on the database when testing whatever sorting/filtering/processing you're doing. It also prevents you from ending up with bad data in the DB in the future that causes your test to "fail."

Comment: Do I write a test based on a new method that returns information from the DB/MockDB or do I write a test based on the existing method to make sure something is returned from calling a new method that returns DB information?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the question, but usually with the repository pattern, you'd create a new class entirely, such as `CustomerRepository`. Then you might create methods such as `GetById` and `GetAll`. You can test that, given a valid customer ID, the repository returns a customer with that ID, or that it returns a list containing multiple customers. Your logic would act on a `List<Customer>` and wouldn't care where that `List` came from.

Answer (score 6):

In general, there's nothing "wrong" about using TDD to test database code. However, you might try abstracting out the database code, then mocking it out.

Comment: Mocking it to return pieces of data from the queries?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. To return specific data for specific tests.

Answer (score 4):

> The method essentially takes 6 parameters, queries a database, does
>   some logic and returns a List

That seems to be *too* much to be a unit testable code!!

A unit testable code should be doing very specific things and doing it in small modules. So, in your case you need to refactor and break your method into following (at least):

- data base query: wrapped inside a DataProvider with a backing interface. And your unit test would mock this interface.
- does some logic : this is the best candidate for a unit test. This should be a module that just takes data provider interface and does the logic and returns modified list which you will validate in your unit test.

Also, remember a unit test should cover at least three scenarios for each testable module:

- a positive test
- a negative test
- test throwing meaningful exception for invalid values.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to start a transaction before the test and do a rollback afterwards.  This way tests are independent so can still, according to some definitions, be considered unit tests.

Contrary to what's mentioned in other answers, you should refactor the code to get to a better design *after* the test passes.  Then you can verify that your refactoring didn't break anything just by rerunning the test.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try looking at [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) for running unit tests on your data access layer.  It puts your database in a known state between test runs preventing corruption of your test database.

Comment: Any .NET equivalent? This question is .NET specific.

Comment: @DannyVarod A quick Google search turned up this project: http://dbunit-net.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Nice, but DAL technology specific. Keeping a demo DB file in source control then copying and attaching would be more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Use the class/test init to raise a blank DB or a copy of small DB with a known set of data.
2. In the test method enter test data (if the DB is empty), then perform the query, then compare result with expect result.
3. In the test/class cleanup remove DB.

This tests your unit but is considered an "integration test" by some.
- The term "unit test" has some disagreement due to the ambiguity of the term "unit".

You could also use an in-memory DB or an in-process DB to make the test environment simpler.